# Foolproof Jailbreak detection?

Tags: ios, detection

I went through various posts which talks about jailbreak detection mechanisms. Whatever I came across is either something that apple would reject during the vetting process or something that could be bypassed. I also came to know that apple removed the jailbreak detection API..

So, is there any foolproof mechanism with which i can check whether a device is jailbroken?

Comment: May I ask why you need to check if the device is jailbroken?

Comment: This will always be (in)security though obscurity.

Comment: You seem to be limiting the question to only apple devices. There are large classes of devices where apple would not be able to reject the mechanism.  And I believe that the standard is not "foolproof" but "adversary proof". There are no security standards that are adversary proof, merely ones that require investments the adversary is unlikely to bear.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to do this programatically from an app because many MDM (Mobile Device Management) tools can do this and have jailbreak detection and then can enforce policy rules (such as "brick the device", "erase data", etc) based on that detection.

Comment: Except no detection will offer 100% foolproof detection of a jailbreak/root